# What does it mean for a group $G=PQ$ for normal subgroups $P$ and $Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

What does it mean for a group $G=PQ$ for normal subgroups $P$ and $Q$? I just can't seem to find a formal definition of this, but it pops up in problems a lot. Does it mean each $g \in G$ is of the form $g = pq$ for $p \in P$ and $q \in Q?$ Does this also mean that $g=qp?$

Comment: Yes. It means that $g \in G$ implies $g = pq$ with $p \in P$ and $q \in Q$. In general, is not necessary that $pq = qp$ since normal groups and abelian groups are not the same thing. The normal hypothesis is because the product of two subgroups is not necessary a group (actually, only one of them needs to be normal).

Comment: Although you cannot say that $g=qp$, you can say that $g=q'p'$ for some $q'\in Q, p'\in P$. That is because $QP=G$ also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $G=PQ$ is a compact way of writing that every element $g$ in $G$ can be written as $pq$ for some $p\in P$ and $q\in Q$. In general, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a group, $AB$ usually the set of products of elements:
$$AB=\{ab: a\in A,b\in B\}.$$

However, if $g=pq$, then $g$ may not also be equal to $qp$. Not necessarily. If $P=Q=G$ and $G$ is non-abelian, then it's possible to pick $p\in P$ and $q\in Q$ with $pq\neq qp$.

However, if every element of $G$ can be represented *uniquely* as a product $pq$ (this is equivalent to $P\cap Q$ only consisting of the identity), then your statement is true. To see this, consider $x=q^{-1}pqp^{-1}$. Then
$$x\in q^{-1}(pQp^{-1})=q^{-1}Q=Q,$$
and
$$x\in (q^{-1}Pq)p^{-1}=Pp^{-1}=P,$$
so $x\in P\cap Q$, and thus $x$ is the identity. So, $pq=qp$. This implies that $G$ is the *direct product* of the groups $P$ and $Q$.

---

A few interesting notes:

1. For *any* subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$, $G=HK$ if and only if $G=KH$. This may be shown by looking at inverses.
2. Above, we shows that $G=PQ$ and $|P\cap Q|=1$ was enough to show that $g=pq$ implies $g=qp$, if $P$ and $Q$ are both normal in $G$. In general, this isn't enough if even one of $P$ and $Q$ is allowed not to be normal. A classic example is $G=S_3$, where $N$ (normal in $G$) is the subgroup of order $3$ and $H$ (not normal) is any subgroup of order $2$. The general name for such constructions is the *semidirect product*.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was interesting and helpful. Is it true that if P and Q are normal and their intersection is trivial that G would then be abelian? I feel intuitively like that is the case but can't seem to convince myself of it.

Comment: @Mike Not necessarily -- $G$ is abelian if and only if $P$ and $Q$ are both abelian.